# How to split file path and file name into components in python?

Tags: python

I would like to split "C:\My Work\Tester Related\A_B_C.txt"
into [C:\, My Work, Tester Related, A, B, C, txt] in Python.

I just started learning Python. I did import os.path module, and played with
some of the functions in the interactive prompt but was not able to get the desired result.
Thanks for the help. I was able to use os.path.basename to get the file, but was not able to split the file into components based on the given delimiter '_'.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `split(file_name,"_")`. But you want it split on several delimiters. Hm.

Comment: Consider replacing `_` with the `os.pathsep` first. Then you'll have a *normalized* path of "C:\My Work\Tester Related\A\B\C.txt"

Comment: It's okay to first separate file path and file name, and split each into components based on their respective delimiters. It does not have to be one step to do all. :)

Comment: What version are you using? If you're on 3.x you could use `*` unpacking with `split`

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention, but I am using version 3.4.1 on Win 7 pro

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "C:\\My Work\\Tester Related\\A_B_C.txt"

import re
print (re.split(r"\\|\.|\_",s))
['C:', 'My Work', 'Tester Related', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'txt']
```

Comment: I got syntax error:>>> s = "C:\My Work\Tester Related\A_B_C.txt"
>>> print re.split(r"\\|\.|\_",s)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: I suggested some edits to Padraic's answer that should resolve the syntax issue.

Comment: @Murchak you might need r"C:\My Work\Tester Related\A_B_C.txt" on windows

Comment: @Murchak, you also need parens for printing

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Of course the parentheses have to be there. But what I was missing was the import re statement. That did the trick. Thanks all. I did search this before posting this question, but couldn't find an answer. So I posted this specific example to not only help me, but others who may have similar questions. The different methods posted here are very instructive. Thanks all.

Comment: One thing that is curious is why the format changes:>>> 'a\b\c\d'.split('\\')
['a\x08', 'c', 'd']. In this example, why not just get ['a','b','c','d'] and instead get 'a\x08'?

Comment: @Murchak did you use `r`?

Answer (score 0):

```
original_path = "C:\My Work\Tester Related\A_B_C.txt"

# Must quote the backslash in this case.
split_path = original_path.split("\\")

# At this point, split_path looks like:
# ['C:', 'My Work', 'Tester Related', 'A_B_C.txt']

split_filename = split_path[-1].split("_")
# split_filename is ['A', 'B', 'C.txt']

split_ext = split_filename[:-1].split(".")
# split_ext is ['C', 'txt']

split_filename = split_filename[:-1] + split_ext
# split_filename is ['A', 'B', 'C', 'txt']

split_path = split_path[:-1] + split_filename
# ['C:', 'My Work', 'Tester Related', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'txt']
```

It's a little hacky but it'll work.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But can the split function take in the whole file path as an argument with a given delimiter to do the splitting? Or must I define a new variable/object and assign to it the file path, then use the split method on this object where the argument of the split method is only the delimiter?

Comment: Hi Murchak, the split function can only split one element at a time. You could, however, use Padraic's excellent answer to do what you'd like in a much more concise way.

Answer (score 0):

an ugly two liner!

```
import itertools
txt = r"C:\\My Work\\Tester Related\\A_B_C.txt"

result = list(itertools.chain(*map(lambda x: x.split('_'), txt.split(os.path.sep))))
result = result[:-1] + list(os.path.splitext(result[-1]))
```

A better method is to use `re`, as @PaedricCunningham did in his answer.

```
re.split(r"\\|\.|_", txt)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Interesting! I briefly skimmed through defining functions using the lambda way. I'll try to understand your code to see how it works.

Comment: @Murchak it's an interesting academic lesson, but don't write code this way. It's unreadble.

Comment: I tried, but got invalid syntax error. I did import itertools first, then type exactly as suggested, got syntax error

Comment: @Murchak try it again. I realized I made several errors and edited about the time you made that last comment :)